# Self hosted WCF console output from service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service

quick one:

Is it possible to capture the output stream of a WCF service that is hosted via ServiceHost ( self hosted service) ? I have methods within my WCF service that output useful debugging information, is it possible to send these to it's host's console output?

Edit:

It appears that I have made an obvious blunder - I was using Debug instead of Console. It is possible to output to the console by using the standard Console output commands in your WCF service class. I have marked the answer that I have found the most useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is relevant to any service that is running as a service host, not just WCF. If you are using a logging framework such as [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) then you have a number of options available to you.

To get something up and running quickly I would suggest the log4net [TelnetAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.TelnetAppender.html) there is a blog post [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/archive/2005/06/16/413437.aspx) that shows you how to wire it up. It will allow you to connect from any machine on the network be it local or your own work station and allow you to see the stream of log messages.

It would also be prudent to have a rolling log file as well for historical information. With logging frameworks it is easy to out put to multiple log dumps.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible for a service to write directly to the console. Diagnostic messages written by services will normally be written to the event log or a log file. But you can start the executable from a commandline and write to console by implementing the solution written by Daniel Root: [Solution for output messages to console](http://www.danielroot.info/2010/01/how-to-write-net-windows-service-with.html)

Answer (score 0):

I just console log like this `System.Console.WriteLine("Save Data Method Hit.");` and it logs in my console  which I used for self hosting WCF service.